# Вертикальный скролл на колонку

Tags: css, html5, вёрстка

[image: проблемка]

Делаю тестовое задание.
И это один из последних моментов.

По условию надо предусмотреть горизонтальную полосу прокрутки для основного контента.
Я её сделал:

```
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

И всё работает хорошо.
Но также при наведении на группу должен появляться еще и индивидуальный скролл.
И вот тут проблемы:
1. Если делать при `hover`, то группы начинают плясать, как дурные.
2. Значительно уменьшается ширина группы, больше чем на ширину полосы.

Видел вроде, с помощью плагинов можно сделать.
Кто сталкивался?

Comment: Хорошо бы код показать.

Comment: Ну ширина меняется это логично, так как скрол появляется и занимает места. 1. Решением может быть увеличение ширины блока на ширину скролла. То есть копенсировать прыганье столбца за счёт увеличение его ширины (тогда прыгнет в растяжку) 2. Задать сразу дополнительное место под скролл, то есть он сразу есть но нивидимый, но при наведении появляется. Тогда прыжка не будет.

Comment: Чтобы не плодить новых тем спрошу тут. Есть поиск в каждом столбце. При наведении появляються Ок и крестик. Пока получилось только для одного элемента сделать, через getElementById, поможет ли замена на querySelectorAll. Или как еще можно сделать?

Comment: github.com/Husach/to_do/tree/master/build Эксперементальным методом установлено - проблемы начинаються когда суммарная ширина колонок превышает ширину блока в котором они находяться. В этом случае как раз блок с hover 'ом  уменьшаеться настолько, чтобы общий блок был без горизонтальной линейки прокрутки.

Comment: Можно сделать везде свой ID и тогда уже поиск по нему, в функции поиска прописывается соответсвующий ID. Либо делать через класс, но у каждого столбца всё-равно должен быть уникальный ID, сначала по нему искать а потом уже по классу внутри него.